# Sort by Log_time but into group section?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How do I sort by Log_time (DESC) but into GroupID section?

Example Data:

```
Field Names:
LogID
GroupID
Log_Output
Log_time


1  | xdsd | Text 1 | 2011-08-08 11:11:00
2  | x42e | Text 2 | 2011-08-08 11:12:00
3  | xdsd | Text 3 | 2011-08-08 11:13:00
4  | x42e | Text 4 | 2011-08-08 11:16:00
5  | x42e | Text 5 | 2011-08-08 11:17:00
6  | xdsd | Text 6 | 2011-08-08 11:20:00
```

I want it to order Like this:

```
6  | xdsd | Text 6 | 2011-08-08 11:20:00
3  | xdsd | Text 3 | 2011-08-08 11:13:00
1  | xdsd | Text 1 | 2011-08-08 11:11:00
5  | x42e | Text 5 | 2011-08-08 11:17:00
4  | x42e | Text 4 | 2011-08-08 11:16:00
2  | x42e | Text 2 | 2011-08-08 11:12:00
```

Comment: what u try till now ? what u get when u try to sort by Log_time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you want to sort by GroupID first, and then Log_Time for each GroupId, then this should do it:

```
select LogID, GroupID, Log_Output, Log_time
from table
order by GroupID, Log_time desc
```

Comment: I have tried that but GroupID is very random ID.  I dont want to sort by GroupID but group/selection by GroupID.  It should be sort by Log_time (DESC) with the matching GroupID. See my example above

Comment: Thats what this is doing. You only need to 'group by' the GroupId if you want to add some sort of aggregate value like the total of some column per GroupId. Maybe I'm missing something? Can you elaborate a bit more on why you don't want to sort by GroupId?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, your SQL did work. Nearly the same from mySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT  LogID, GroupID, Log_Output, Log_time
  FROM mytable
    ORDER BY GroupID, Log_time DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Use MySQL Query `select a, b, c from table_name order by c desc`